# Most efficient way to scale re-usable web crawler? (Python/Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, indexing, web-crawler

First off, please excuse the open-endedness of this question and any lack of technical language. I am a self-taught programmer and while I have a reasonably good grasp of Python for my own purposes, I'm far less familiar with broader organization and scaling of projects.

I've developed a Selenium-based web crawler which I've been using to crawl web-sites with dynamic content, handle authorization, and collect html and pdf-based data. I intend to work out a way to index this content (using something like Solr or similar) so that it can be searched, but I have not gotten to this stage yet.

My goal is for this web crawler to be reusable so that I can create a new instances of this web crawler for multiple different sites. This would require parameters such as start URLs, allowed domains/URL patterns (using regex), excluded URLs, and optional boolean parameters such as `login_required` and an associated component to handle authentication for that specific site.

I've currently structured this under a `Crawler` class (code shared below), but I'm doubtful if this is the most efficient way to go about this. My main questions are:

1. What is the best way to structure this type of crawler so that it can be re-used for multiple projects, either through a reusable class or something like a JSON-based config file (or other)?
2. How can I include optional parameters and importing additional components based on the value of those parameters (such as a method to handle login for a specific site?)
3. How can I a set number run multiple crawlers concurrently, while adding other crawlers to a queue to be run?

I hope this is not too vague - any guidance or input is much appreciated! I am happy with the state of the web crawler and its ability to handle what I need, but am not sure where to go from here.

Current structure of the `Crawler` class is below:

```
import re
import os
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

class Crawler:
    def __init__(self, name, domain, startURIs, URIs, maxDepth):
        self.name = name
        self.domain = domain
        self.startURIs = startURIs
        self.URIs = URIs
        self.maxDepth = maxDepth
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.download_dir = ''
        self.profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],"download.default_directory": self.download_dir, "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"}
        self.options.add_experimental_option("prefs", self.profile)
        self.options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/Users/usr/Projects/Web Crawler/User_data')
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=self.options)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
```

PS: I have experimented with other web crawling libraries such as Scrapy, but have found that Selenium in this case best fits my purposes (even if it does run slower).

Comment: I use an XML based structure for storing procedures/actions.  (file-based)  Then have a class that runs those procedures (a "procedure" is just an array of actions).  There are flags you can set at run-time that do various things... one of which is setting a "map-file" for doing things like placing variables in specific actions, setting files for "data-loop procedures".  You can find an example of this implementation here: https://www.thebrowserbots.com   (the backend stores "site logins" with indexes) Which uses my application/framework "The Browsermator": https://www.browsermator.com

Comment: So the back-end serves the files needed for a particular "bot".  (The xml file based "script" or "browsermation" file, any associated map-files, data-files or site-login data which is just the site name + index for username and password.  Username/password is stored locally encrypted with the machine's serial number.)  My framework is not all that useful for scraping... other than storing links/urls.  It's main focus is for testing, but might give you an idea of how to implement your own cloud-based scapers.